# Chrome Extension Pass URL To OS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My extension has a context menu where selected text can be sent to a program on the OS via a URl Protocol registered with the OS (Windows). However, The only way I can find to get the URL to the OS is to create an unneeded tab or window with the extension, i.e.,

```
url = "winprogram://data...";
chrome.tabs.create({url});
```

Creating the tab will pass the URL to the OS and open the program with the included parameters, but I don't want the new tab. I also tried a XMLHttpRequest send, but the extension complained it was not the same origin.

Is there a way to get the URL to the OS without creating a tab?

Comment: What about creating an iframe in your background page?

Comment: @rsanchez From what I read from the Google docs, https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external, iframes have the same security restrictions as XMLHttpRequests, though I have not tried it.

Comment: That page is about apps, not extensions.

Comment: True on the page. I made an iframe inn the background page and set the URL to custom URL with JS and it works without opening a tab! Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!